# I am trying to test my real time facebook like chat app in localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, socket.io

to test the app I am using Chrome normal window for one user and incognito window for another user.
non of the sockets sends data to the user using the incognito window. however they send data between the frond and backend but only for the user who is invoking them.
is it wrong the way I am testing using the same local machine.

here is some snippets:

client side:

```
  submit() {
      if (this.text) {
        this.socket.emit("new-message", {
          text: this.text,
          sender: this._id,
          receiver: this.userPop._id,
          date: Date.now(),
          seen: false,
        });
        const msg = {
          text: this.text,
          sender: this._id,
          receiver: this.userPop._id,
          date: Date.now(),
          seen: false,
        };

        this.sent.push(msg);
        this.text = "";
```

```
 this.socket.on("fetch-message", async (data) => console.log(data));
```

```
 text(value) {
      value
        ? this.socket.emit("sender_typing", {
            receiver: this.userPop.first_name,
            receiver_id: this.userPop._id,
            sender_id:this._id,
            sender: this.user.first_name, 
            senderSocketId: this.socket.id,
          })
        : this.socket.emit("stopTyping");
    },
```

```
 mounted() {
    this.socket.on("typing", async (data) => {
      await console.log(data.receiver_id , data.sender_id);
       if (this._id === data.receiver_id) {
        this.typing = data.sender;
      
      }
    });

    this.socket.on("stop_typing", () => {
      this.typing = "";
    });
    // this.socket.on("seen_server", (data)=>{
    //   this.seen= data.message
    // })
  },
```

backend sockets:

```
socket.on("new-message", async(data)=>{
   await console.log(data)
 
   await Message.create(data)
    .then(async (msg) => {
      return msg.save();
    })
    .then(async (msg) => {
      const newMsg = await msg.toObject();
      console.log(newMsg);
     socket.emit('fetch-message',{newMsg})
    })
    .catch(err=> console.log(err))
  })
```

```
socket.on("sender_typing", async(data) => {
   await console.log(data)
   socket.emit('typing', {
     sender: data.sender,
     sender_id:data.sender_id,
     socket_id: socket.id,
     receiver_id:data.receiver_id,
    })
    
  });
```

Comment: It's not answer for your question. But you don't need to await for console.logs.

Comment: Yes I  know but somehow inside the socket it does not till I do sync wait